# Place serial number beside

Tags: html, css

I am developing a web app which has questions and i have to place question numbers beside the questions 
The format is supposed to be like this

```
Q10. - - - - - - - -
     - - - - - - - -
     - - - - - - - -
```

I have tried to make it an ordered list but that doesn't work because I have to dynamically place question numbers

```
.question {
  margin-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
.question::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried adding two paragraphs side by side one having the question number and the other containing the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to @dfsq's answer I think a more appropriate option, although using similar structure would be the use of `data-attributes`.

```css
.question {
  margin-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
.question::before {
  content: "Q" attr(data-question);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -2em;
}
```

```html
<p class="question" data-question="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores sit iste dolore commodi facere atque ab aut ratione repudiandae assumenda porro animi autem molestiae. Optio eaque perferendis quod inventore eius nobis aspernatur facilis quo voluptate.</p>

<p class="question" data-question="11">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores sit iste dolore commodi facere atque ab aut ratione repudiandae assumenda porro animi autem molestiae. Optio eaque perferendis quod inventore eius nobis aspernatur facilis quo voluptate.</p>
```

This is similar in to the other answer in that it does rely on a 'manual' value being in the HTML but it doesn't rely on `<style>` tags. Very similar methodology.

Whether data-attributes are more accessible to JS is arguable of course, but I throw this out as another option.

Comment: This is really good. It's just I was answering to little different problem (how I thought). I thought that there should be a list of items with initial number, then it's convenient to just define one stating index and have all the items automatically get numbered. So only one style is needed. In this case every li has to have data attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good use for [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters). Check it out how you can use it even with custom initial value:

```css
.questions {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.questions li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Q" counter(section) ".";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="questions" style="counter-reset: section 3">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quam perspiciatis tempore velit voluptatibus cumque ex necessitatibus officiis excepturi nisi neque possimus dolorum nostrum voluptate nesciunt nobis iusto porro laboriosam!</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nulla saepe dicta tedebitis! Aliquam ad similique enim!</li>
    <li>Question #3</li>
    <li>Question #4</li>
</ol>
```

Note, that I have put `style` attribute on the `ol` because you *"have to dynamically place question numbers"*.

Comment: but i have only one question per page and the next question loads on a new page

Comment: okay, so you know the number of the next question, just put it in `style="counter-reset: section <%= questionNumber %>>"`.